# Android Automatically Adds Shortcuts To Home Screen

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-3, home-screen-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I remove unwanted app icons from the screen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37327/how-can-i-remove-unwanted-app-icons-from-the-screen)

I have a Samsung GS3, and every few days new shortcuts show up on my home screen. How can I stop them from being added? I un-checked `Play > Settings > Auto-Add Widgets` and they still keep showing up. What is causing this?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the shortcuts?

Comment: See also my answer [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37327/16575/37332#37332) on a similar question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have installed some non-reliable app, which is adding those annoying shortcuts in your home screen. I recommend you to install and make a scan with the free app [TrustGo Ad Detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trustgo.addetector), and uninstall the app(s) under the behavior **Create shortcut on home screen**.

[image: List of apps with undesired behaviors] [image: Suspicious App description]

Also check out under the other behaviors for more suspicious apps and proceed as recommended. Note that some apps use *legitimate* mobile ad services, like **Google's AdMob** to monetize via ads, but they are listed under behaviors **Leak identity info** and **Collect location** , so just make sure you only uninstall (and avoid to install in the future) applications like online casino games, adult apps/games, and other which you distrust.

Keep making scans periodically (weekly or monthly) on your device to get rid of new potentially risky apps.

Comment: Thanks, it found a calculator widget that it said was adding them, I will have to give it a few days before I know if removing it worked or not.

Comment: After reading comments on that app others had the same issue, so I am going to mark this as solved thanks! Here was the culprit: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=foralt.calculator.widget

Comment: Thanks for the info: don't forget to report that calculator widget in Google Play Store because of this kind of spam.

Comment: I have been trying to find a link or something to report this app, but I can not fine one. Any help on this?

Comment: From your smartphone open the Play Store link you shared above and go to bottom, as this image shows (as reason, select "Other objection", and tell them the way that app spammed you): http://i.stack.imgur.com/zSKnX.png