# How to see which app created shortcuts on my home screen?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts

I have a Samsung S7, and lately some apps or virus started to create shortcuts to ads on my homescreen that look like app icons. I removed a lot of new apps but the phenomenon sticks. Usually the thug app creates shortcuts during the mid-night when I am asleep. I like to find how exactly which app is doing this. Thanks.

Comment: Have you already checked one of the many related questions: [Android Automatically Adds Shortcuts To Home Screen](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/37590/16575) / [“Lucky try” & “Recommended” shortcuts always appear on homescreen, how to remove it?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/102382/16575) / [How to Block Third Party Apps from Creative Spam Shortcuts on Home Screen?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/147625/16575) / [Who is creating icons?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/33581/16575)

Comment: @Izzy "Who is creating icons?" seems to be the same question, unfortunately no one came up with an answer yet. I assume it might not be possible. I am looking into the launcher.db as we speak at this moment.

Comment: Let me give you some additional pointers. I've already pointed to the question, but check this specific answer on [“Lucky try” & “Recommended” shortcuts always appear on homescreen, how to remove it?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/102402/16575), and a related one on [How to find installed apps which are using SMS feature](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/116382/16575). Your candidate requires the [`INSTALL_SHORTCUT`](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/perms#INSTALL_SHORTCUT) permission. With that in mind, procedure is the same.

Comment: @izzy is it possible that what is creating the shortcuts is a virus and doesn't show up on the application list? I already removed all the apps having the permission to `INSTALL_SHORTCUT`.

Comment: A virus is very unlikely (as none exists for Android). But if some malware was able to acquire system privileges, yes: It might hide as well as not need specific permissions to do anything. And before you ask: in that case, a factory-reset won't help (as it doesn't touch system apps).

Comment: @Izzy I see. I dug into launcher.db and I couldn't find the creator of these shortcuts. The shortcut showed up last night has an intent of `http://lvxin.kaixinmt.com/h5/lvxing.html#Intent;launchFlags=0x10000000;package=com.sec.android.app.sbrowser;end`.

Comment: Ah, that's another pointer. The URL contained points to a Chinese site (redirecting to another one). And LVXING – well, probably ads for sunglasses. That URL would be launched with your browser. As that domain is [hosted in China & owned by a Chinese company](http://whois.domaintools.com/kaixinmt.com): Any Chinese apps left on your device which you've added "lately", does that ring a bell?

Comment: @lzzy The thing is, they are all gone. I am using Addons Dector to monitor my shortcuts and hopefully I get to catch the malware.