# How can I determine what app put a spam shortcut on my home screen?

Tags: applications, home-screen, logging, intents, spam

Recently, I discovered that some app on my phone had taken it upon itself to place a very nice "Free Games" shortcut on my home screen. I haven't installed any new apps in the recent past, so I would be very curious to find out what Application is behind this.

I've dumped logcat (with 'logcat -v time > log.txt') and gotten the last several hours of logs, but I have no idea what intent to search for.

Is it possible to find the culprit this way? If not, how can I proceed with my witch hunt?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Related http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37327/how-can-i-remove-unwanted-app-icons-from-the-screen/37332#37332